# How can I serialize base class when working with instance of derived class?

Tags: c#, serialization, inheritance, derived-class

Have the following structure

```
[Serializable]
public class Parent
{
    public int x = 5;
}

[Serializable]
public class Child : Parent
{
    public HashAlgorithm ha; //This is not Serializable

}
```

I want to serialize this using the following code:

```
public class Util {
    static public byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I am working with objects of type `Child` in my code, however, I have a field within the `Child` object that is non-serializable (for example: HashAlgorithm). Hence, I attempted the convert to type `Parent` using the below code:

```
public byte[] tryToSerialize(Child c)
{
    Parent p = (Parent) c;
    byte[] b = Util.ObjectToByteArray(p);
    return b;
}
```

However, this returns the error that `HashAlgorithm` is not serializable, despite trying to serialize the child which does not include this field. How can I accomplish what I need?

Comment: In this case, it sounds like the correct fix is [NonSerialized], as already noted. But as an aside, re the specific question, this "ignore the subtype" is something on my list of tweaks for protobuf-net (it simply means *not* doing something, so is a simple fix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.
You cannot serialize a class as one of its base classes.

Instead, add `[NonSerialized]` to the field.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement ISerializable in the base class and then just pass things from derived like:

```
private Child() { } // Make sure you got a public/protected one in Parent

private Child(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
     : base(info, context) { }
```

After you implement ISerializable just use the Serialize method from Child.